# Camel: onException vs. interceptSendToEndpoint

Tags: exception, error-handling, apache-camel, intercept

I am using camel 2.10 with JPA.
I have 2 routes in my context.
Route 1 consumes from a JPA endpoint (db table), does some processing (in a bean) and then forwards the message to route 2. If something goes wrong during processing, the bean returns NULL.

first thing I want to do in route 2 is to check if the body (forwarded from route 1) isn't NULL.
Thus, I see 2 possibilities:
1) using validate in route 2

```
<route id="route2">
...
<validate>
  <simple>${body} != null</simple>
</validate>
```

2) using interceptSendToEndpoint to avoid NULL message being sent to route 2 att all:

```
<interceptSendToEndpoint uri="toRoute2" skipSendToOriginalEndpoint="true">
  <when><simple>${body} == null</simple></when>
  <transform>
    <constant>Error Message</constant>
  </transform>
  <to uri="direct:logError"/>
</interceptSendToEndpoint>
```

what do you think is the better way?

thanks for your suggestions!

BR
Matthias

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's a matter of interfaces.

If NULL payload is considered an error, I would instead throw an exception. Typcially by modifying the processing bean and `throw new RuntimeException("some error msg");` instead of  `return null;`. If not possible, you could always wrap the bean in another bean throwing instead of returning null - or essentially do what you do in 1. Exceptions hook into the normal error handlers also, if you you want to do some error logging etc.

Using intercepts can be very powerful, but also makes the route less obvious - when you revisit the code after some years. It's a bit overkill for such a simple scenario.

Comment: Hi Petter, thanks for your feedback! I cannot modify (all) beans and throw exceptions directly, but wrapping them in another bean sounds like a good idea! if I understand u correctly, u would also prefer this approach to my firstly suggested idea "1) using validate in route 2"?

Comment: Well, depends. If you are using the bean in multiple places, a warpper + exception might be better, you could also customize the exception (specific error message and what not). The validation thing is, however, better if you feel like having all the logic inside the camel route XML.